# Sample consent statement for basic online dictionary project?

Tags: dictionary

Does anyone have an example of a very simple consent statement that could be used on a webpage that collects linguistic (primarily lexical) data?

A guy I know is doing some basic dialectical research and asked me about this. He'd like to come up with a one-sentence statement accompanied by a checkbox that (1) guarantees anonymity for submissions, (2) explains that data may be used for research and possible publication, and (3) explains that this is a non-commercial project. Or something like that. Maybe there are other considerations that need to be addressed, but the idea is to have a simple statement that wouldn't overwhelm anyone or discourage anyone from participating.

All the checkbox examples he or I have found link to a complicated, multi-page consent form.

I believe the questions on the page would be fairly basic, e.g., there'd be an image and the respondent would be asked to identify it using a word from his or her dialect.

Perhaps the respondent would be asked to say where he or she lives, but I'm not sure that respondents' demographics are going to be included in this very basic exercise. It's not for any kind of peer-reviewed study, though I think my friend would like to compile results and put them online, if only to prompt discussion.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you should try and google surveys + privacy statements. This is not a linguistics question...

Comment: I've done a good bit of searching on the topic. I thought someone here might have had experience with exactly this situation. Collecting dictionary data is a bit different from other types of surveys. But I'll lower my expectations for an answer here, in any case.

Comment: Someone else will probably say the same thing. Your question is not about linguistics.

Comment: https://www.formpl.us/blog/how-to-draft-a-survey-disclaimer-important-laws-examples You need to write your own. Here is a guide for that.

Comment: This is one thing that ChatGPT is good at.